# How to add conditional route in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I'm building an attendance system.

When i click on search button, i want to navigate to another screen based on **if condition** in view model

//View

```
        Button("Search"){
            loginVM.fetchUser(cId: civil_id, eId: emp_id)
        }
```

//View Model

```
func fetchUser(cId: String?, eId: Int?) {
        let apiService = RegisterDataSource()
        
        apiService.searchEmployee2(civilId: cId, employeeId: eId) { (result: Result<ResultContent?, APIError>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let user):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.resultContent = user
                }
                guard let regStatusID = self.resultContent?.regStatusID else{ return }
                
                // Employee Found
                if(Vontime().key == nil || Vontime().key == ""){
                    // Local Data Not Founded
                    if(regStatusID == 0 || regStatusID == 1){
                        
                        //MARK: Go To Employee Validation Screen
                        
                    } else if (regStatusID == 2){
                        var style = ToastStyle()
                        style.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
                        style.textColor = UIColor.white
                        ToastManager.showToast("employee_waiting", duration: ToastManager.LENGHT_LONG, position: .bottom, style: style)
                    } 
                }
```

I think i need to create a route,
anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a @Published var in your ViewModel and do the navigation with updating that variable.

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var navigateToEmployeeValidationScreenActive = false

func fetchUser(cId: String?, eId: Int?) {
    .
    .
    .
    if(regStatusID == 0 || regStatusID == 1){
        navigateToEmployeeValidationScreenActive = true
        return
    }
    .
    .
    .
  }
}


struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject viewModel: MyViewModel

var body: some View {
    Vstack {
        
        Text("Some Texts")
        
        if viewModel.navigateToEmployeeValidationScreenActive {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: EmployeeValidationView()
            ),
            isActive: $navigateToEmployeeValidationScreenActive,
            label: {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .hidden()
        }
    }
    
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately this way is Deprecated
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(_:isactive:destination:)-gn8q